# Remove comma generated by multiple select attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, multiselect-attribute

I have created an multiple select attribute, visible on the frondend, it is generated with a comma as a seperator, does anyone know how to remove this comma between the shown values?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Where exactly do you see the comma?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a `frontend model` for this attribute. Frontend models help manipulate the display of attributes in the fronend of Magento. Your code can simply take the value and then manipulate it into the format that you want to show it.

If you look at the model `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Datetime` as an example you can see the following things you need for your model:

1. That it must extend `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract`,
2. That is needs a function `getValue` which will take the object that your are dealing with and then return the value formatted how you want it,

You will need to update your attribute so that it uses this model ideally via a setup script.